# cropper is not a function on is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, canvas, crop

I'm trying to make use of [cropper plugin by fengyuanchen](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper) but meeting quite an impossible error

I constantly get into `Uncaught TypeError: canvas.cropper` is not a function even though I already tried everything I searched in your guide and even issues but I couldn't solve it. I try to initialize a cropper in canvas when my button is clicked, like this

```
$('#crop-mode').click(function(e){
                    var canvas=$('#image-display canvas')[0];
                    var options={
                        viewMode:0,
                        dragMode:'crop',
                        aspectRatio: NaN,
                        preview:'.extra-preview',
                        responsive:true,
                        cropBoxMovable: true,
                        cropBoxResizable: true,
                        autoCropArea:0.8
                    };
                    canvas.cropper(options);
                    canvas.on({
                        'build.cropper': function (e) {
                            console.log(e.type);
                        },
                        'built.cropper': function (e) {
                            console.log(e.type);
                        },
                        'cropstart.cropper': function (e) {
                            console.log(e.type, e.action);
                        },
                        'cropmove.cropper': function (e) {
                            console.log(e.type, e.action);
                        },
                        'cropend.cropper': function (e) {
                            console.log(e.type, e.action);
                        },
                        'crop.cropper': function (e) {
                            console.log(e.type, e.x, e.y, e.width, e.height, e.rotate, e.scaleX, e.scaleY);
                        },
                        'zoom.cropper': function (e) {
                            console.log(e.type, e.ratio);
                        }
                    });
                });
```

I'm completely in vain

There is also another error: `canvas.on is not a function`

I don't know why. I already include jQuery 3.1

Comment: Post your HTML as well. What is the value of `canvas` after the second line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the jQuery docs:

> Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

Now, `canvas` after `var canvas=$('#image-display canvas')[0];` is not a selected element. It's the first property of the selected element. `$()` will return a selected element (if found, obviously), but `$()[0]` is something completely else. Drop the `[0]`.

Comment: It is still the same. Nothing changes. Still that error

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it. It should be `$canvas` and `$canvas.cropper`, also `$canvas.on` after removing `[0]`

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have the library loaded with jquery:

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/cropper.js"></script>
```

Cropper is a jquery extension, thus instead of:

```
var canvas=$('#image-display canvas')[0];
```

do:

```
var canvas=$('#image-display canvas');
```

Comment: I did include jQuery before adding Cropper. Anyway, I fixed it successfully. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to download the correct package with

> npm install cropper

Please don't use this

> npm install cropperjs

as Cropper.js is not a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This will work definitely >> after following every step correctly as mention in link-https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-editor   .
do only this.>>>   goto your angular node module find >>>ngx-image-editor/esm5/ngx-image-editor.js >>> here you can import>>>import {default as Cropper} from 'cropperjs'; and refresh your node module  and save ...

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are with jQuery you have to import the cropper library file,

```
<script src="/plugin/cropper/cropper.js"></script>
<script src="/plugin/cropper/jquery-cropper.js"></script>
<link href="'/plugin/cropper/cropper.css'" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Remember! You still have to have jQuery above this all.